# SSMA Oracle To SQL 2008 - Oracle db To blank SQL Database

Tags: sql-server, oracle, database-migration, sql-server-migration-assi

I am new to Oracle,  I am using the SSMA for Oracle tool to do the migration work.

I am having some issues migrating data from an Oracle database to a blank SQL Database. I have followed the guides I have found online but still no luck.
I cannot seem to get the data(I only need tables) from the Oracle Database into the Blank SQL Database.

I have the tables within a Schema named System.  I have expanded the Schema and selected the tables checkbox on my Oracle connection, when doing the migration I always get: 
**Data migration was not performed because no objects were selected.** When selecting migrate data and putting in my connection details etc.

I have tried to select the destination database under the Server explorer at the bottom and right clicked and selected Synchronize with database however I get:
**Nothing to process by this operation, because all objects are equal.**
Can someone please shed some light on what I have failed to do?

Could it be related to the System Schema?

Thanks,

Comment: I think this may be the issue. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2020714

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to work around this. you cannot migrate from the SYSTEM schema as per: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2020714

However what I did was used Redgate Oracle Compare(free trial) to migrate objects from the SYSTEM Schema to my target Schema.  I could then right click this schema in SSMA to convert Schema and proceed with the migration.

Comment: a better option still was to specify the TOUSER=SchemaName in the IMP command line import when importing the data into Oracle, this put the data into the correct schema.